# Draw detailed git graphs with mermaid - layout

Tags: git, diagram, mermaid

I am trying to draw git diagrams with mermaid, using flowchart as an alternative to [mermaid gitgraph-diagrams](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gitgraph). The main reason is to show the branches and HEAD pointers on the graph.
As example:

```
    flowchart RL;
      3((9817e0))-->1((e137e9));
      4((ae3e0f))-->3;
      id2(main) -.-> idHead
      id1(HEAD) -.-> id2(main)
      idHead((e2d9e6))-->6;
      idHead-->4;
      5((a1fbcd))-->3;
      52((86d91f))--> 5
      6((711a58))-->52;
      id3(dev) -.-> 6
    
      style id1 fill:#b8dbbc,stroke:#333,stroke-width:1px
      style id2 fill:#f96,stroke:#333,stroke-width:1px
      style id3 fill:#f90,stroke:#333,stroke-width:1px
      style idHead fill:#b8dbbc
```

[image]

Is there a way to draw the pointers "main", "dev", HEAD, on top or down the nodes, not in the same line? The desired result would be like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Mermaid has a built in module for [git graphs](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gitgraph) - what's wrong with using that one?

Comment: If you don't have to use Mermaid, the [gitdags](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags) package for LaTeX can do this.

Comment: Thaks for pointing gitdags.